# Sorting using both ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have election table, I want to sort the first column in ascending order and last column in descending order but it is not giving desired output.The last column should also be sorted in descending order. This is the query I have used

```
SELECT *
FROM election
WHERE PARTY = 'IND' ORDER BY 'AC_NO' ASC ,'VOTES' DESC
```

thanks in advance

```
AC_NO  CAND_NO  PARTY  VOTES 
 1       10      IND   240 
 1       11      IND   315 
 1       12      IND   564 
 1       13      IND   1197 
 1       14      IND   1070 
 2        6      IND   782 
 2        8      IND   502
```

Answer (score 2):

use query as per below-

```
SELECT *
FROM election
WHERE PARTY = 'IND' ORDER BY `AC_NO` ASC ,`VOTES` DESC
```

You were using '' means column were treated as variable.

Comment: Hey thanks for that information ..........it worked without using " `  ` " as well                                  SELECT * FROM election WHERE  PARTY = 'IND' ORDER BY AC_NO ASC , VOTES DESC;

Comment: yes backquotes is not compulsory in every case just mysql show it in blue color if mysql uses that like STATUS word as column name....you may also accept this as answer by green tick if you feel it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM `election` ORDER BY `AC_NO`,`VOTES` DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks...but in my case I jus wanted to retrieve the records of column where the value is 'IND'